# Como retornar um dado mesmo se a tabela não tem dados

Tags: postgresql, query, join

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de eu retornar um valor mesmo que o resultado da consulta seja nulo, por exemplo na consulta abaixo eu tento retornar o **id 0** caso a **table1** seja **null**.
Tentei usar CROSS JOIN mas não tive bons resultados.

`SELECT COALESCE(tab.id, 0) id_tabela FROM table1 tab WHERE tab.id IS NULL`

Comment: Não vejo nenhum cenário que retornar um "registro fake" seria algo bom. Para que você quer isto?

Comment: Como assim? "Geração espontânea"? Surgindo do nada?

Comment: Eu estou construindo um relatório, mas caso a linha da minha select retorne um valor nulo eu preciso criar uma linha fake com valores zerados, pensei em fazer isso no Java, porém me daria muito trabalho, então estou tentando resolver via select. @TiedtTech

Comment: Talvez o que precise seja utilizar a função `COALESCE`. Mas veja que não estará criando algo inexistente só está substituindo a exibição de valores NULL. Não vejo aonde um CROSS JOIN ajudaria em seu problema.

Comment: Então o que procuro é uma forma de criar esse dado, e como disse o `COALESCE`, não esta ajudando

Comment: Fiz um exemplo simples no http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb4fb/4. Olha se é isto mesmo que você deseja? O único problema deste SQL é que vai ter que replicar os `where`

Comment: Não tem problema replicar os `where`, no meu caso, acho que sua solução resolve meu problema. Muito obrigado por ajudar, e desculpa por qualquer formatação errada no post ou por falta de clareza. @TiedtTech

Comment: Tipo de problema recorrente pois quase sempre é o pior cenário , cliente sem compra , bairro sem médico etc.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode escrever uma function para isso:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION esta_vazia() RETURNS text language plpgsql as $_$
DECLARE
    registros record;
BEGIN
    SELECT *
      INTO registros
      FROM table1;

    IF (registros isnull) THEN
        RETURN 'a tabela está vazia';
    END IF;

    RETURN 'Tabela ocupada';

END;
$_$;
```

Para testar se o resultado utilize:

```
select esta_vazia();
```

Observe o resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]